# Positioning items with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am still learning so I am struggling with CSS. I want to align all items within div centrally and align pics with the text and align them to left.

HTML

```
     <div class='SectionTop'>
               <div class='CardVisual'>
                   <p class='CardName'> <img src="templates/img/GlobePic.jpg" alt="" class="Pic"> Countries </p>
                   <p class='CardValue'> {{countryNumber}} </p> 
               </div>
               <div class='CardVisual'>
                   <p class='CardName'> <img src="templates/img/BuildingPic.jpg" alt="" class="Pic"> Customers </p>
                   <p class='CardValue'> {{customerNumber}} </p>
                </div> 
      </div>
```

CSS

```
    .SectionTop {
     width: 95%;
     margin-left: 3%;
     margin-right: 3%;
     background-color: white;
     border: 2px solid blue;
     border-radius: 25px;
      }
            
.CardVisual {        
width: 15%;
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
}
.Pic {
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
object-fit: cover;
margin-left: 20px;
align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of `display: flex` to achieve this one.

```css
.SectionTop {
  width: 95%;
  margin-left: 3%;
  margin-right: 3%;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  border-radius: 25px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  height: 250px;
}

.CardVisual {
  width: 15%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
.Pic {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  object-fit: cover;
  margin-left: 20px;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="SectionTop">
  <div class="CardVisual">
    <p class="CardName">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/cinqueterre.jpg" alt="" class="Pic" /> Countries
    </p>
    <p class="CardValue">001</p>
  </div>
  <div class="CardVisual">
    <p class="CardName">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/cinqueterre.jpg" alt="" class="Pic" />
      Customers
    </p>
    <p class="CardValue">002</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped, although I used:
justify-content: space-between to spread it out

Answer (score 0):

For the centering purposes, use *text-align: center*. Unfortunately without a valid image I cant figure out exactly what you require.

```css
.SectionTop {
  width: 95%;
  margin-left: 3%;
  margin-right: 3%;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  border-radius: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}

.CardVisual {
  width: 15%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.Pic {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  object-fit: cover;
  margin-left: 20px;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='SectionTop'>
  <div class='CardVisual'>
    <p class='CardName'> <img src="templates/img/GlobePic.jpg" alt="" class="Pic"> Countries </p>
    <p class='CardValue'> {{countryNumber}} </p>
  </div>
  <div class='CardVisual'>
    <p class='CardName'> <img src="templates/img/BuildingPic.jpg" alt="" class="Pic"> Customers </p>
    <p class='CardValue'> {{customerNumber}} </p>
  </div>
</div>
```